# Struts2 with maven no Action mapped for namespace and action name associated with context path

Tags: java, jsp, struts2

Although it is a common problem but I cannot figure it out.

I am running Strut2 with maven project. My project structure is given bellow

[image] is

**Product.java**

```
package beans;

public class Product {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private float price;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }    
}
```

**ProductAction.java**

```
package actions;

import beans.Product;

public class ProductAction{

    public Product getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(Product product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    private Product product;

    public String execute(){
       return "success";
    }
}
```

**struts.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts
Configuration 2.1//EN" "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.1.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
    <package name="default" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="product" class="actions.ProductAction" method="execute">
            <result name="success">welcome.jsp</result>
        </action>    
    </package>
</struts>
```

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<div>
    <%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>
    <s:form action="product">
        <s:textfield name="product.id" label="Product Id"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="product.name" label="Product Name"></s:textfield>
        <s:textfield name="product.price" label="Product Price"></s:textfield>
        <s:submit value="save"></s:submit>
    </s:form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and **welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>

Product Id:<s:property value="id"/><br/>
Product Name:<s:property value="name"/><br/>
Product Price:<s:property value="price"/><br/>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using Glassfish server. It runs index.jsp well. But when I fill the form and submit it shows

> HTTP Status 404 - There is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and
>   action name [product] associated with context path [/deploytest].
>
> type Status report
>
> messageThere is no Action mapped for namespace [/] and action name
>   [product] associated with context path [/deploytest].
>
> descriptionThe requested resource is not available.
>
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1

My **pom.xml** has dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.28</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: There action configuration is missing.

Comment: The configuration for the second action is there, there is no action for the first JSP, that should break on s:textfield tags then. You're not telling us the thruth @syed :)

Comment: **web.xml**  contains the welcome file name.

Comment: I does not redirect to welcome page.But index.jsp runs ok

Comment: @syedmhamudulhasanakash You don't need a welcome file with S2 tags inside it.

Comment: To use struts tags you need an actioncontext. To create an actioncontext you need to execute an action. You *can* use a JSP as welcome page, but you should not have any struts tag inside it, otherwise you should get another type of error... then your struts.xml is most likely not the one you've posted here

Comment: But you should know (just remarking @Quaternion) that everything that is going to the Struts2 is an action. I believe that you can access the welcome file because you have served it directly, but not in the case from the directory.